# How to get a dynamic JQuery Selector from js function parameter value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function and i qould to create a jquery selector, which was build from js function parameter value:

```
function myJSFunction(elementId){
    var showSomeData= {
        'value_1': 'abc',
        'value_2': 'xyz'
    };

    var selector = "[name=" + elementId + "] option";
    jQuery("'" + selector + "'").each(function() {
         $(this).attr('title', showSomeData[$(this).val()]);
    });
};
```

But this kind of code doesn´t work. If i set the concrete value, which i can see in the html dom by using firebug, this code works fine. What was my mistake?

Comment: You don't need `"'"`again, use directly : `jQuery(selector)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$("'" + selector + "'")` use `$(selector)` and your issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, you don't need `"'"` again to find the elements, use directly : `jQuery(selector)`:

```
var selector = "[name=" + elementId + "] option";
jQuery(selector).each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', showSomeData[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove Quotes

```
 var selector = "[name=" + elementId + "] option";
    $(selector).each(function(i,val) {


    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h36ST/10/)**